# Boat crossing a river problem

Tags: vectors, problem-solving, mathematical-physics

> A ferry boat crosses a river and arrives at a point on the opposite bank directly across from its starting point. The boat can travel at 6m/s and the current is 2m/s. If the river is 700m wide, in what direction must the boat steer and how long will it take to cross?

This is exactly how the question is worded in my textbook. In "Applications of the dot and cross products" and I'm a little stumped by this one because there is no indication of what direction the current is flowing. So trying to figure out a specific direction is what's stumping me here. Also having some trouble determining the time to cross.

Comment: You can give an angle "against the current" measured from going straight across

Comment: There is a minor glitch in the problem.  "The boat can travel at 6m/s".  Clearly, in order to make the problem solvable, you are to assume that the boat would travel at 6m/s, if there was no current.  So, you are supposed to aim the boat moderately against the current, letting the current *bring you back* to the opposite point.

Comment: Re last comment, I don't know from boats.  My intuition questions whether the strain on the engine is greater, for the boat to maintain a 6m/s speed, when going against the current.  However, clearly, you are to ignore such considerations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously , the current has to flow against the boat to make it arrive at a point exactly opposite to the starting position.

[See the Vector Triangle Diagram here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gwnA-IVdjNQVy6T810mxG4Z4BMu1hQtr/view?usp=sharing)

**$\vec vel_{boat,ground}= \vec vel_{boat,river} + \vec vel_{river,ground}$**

You need to solve the above vector equation using the triangle law.

You know that $\vec vel_{boat,ground}$ is at angle of 90° to the direction of the $\vec vel_{river,ground}$

The angle of tilt will then be: $cos^{-1}(1/3) = 70.53°$ (approx.)

For the magnitude of the $vel_{boat,ground}$, you apply the Pythogoras Theorem to the same triangle:

$vel_{boat,ground}^2= vel_{boat, river}^2 - vel_{river,ground}^2$

Or

$vel_{boat,ground}^2 = 6^2 - 2^2$

Or

$vel_{ boat,ground}$ = 5.656 m/sec.

The time is then simply

$700/5.656$

or 123.76 sec.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thank you for the welcome. I will definitely check out the writing and editing guidelines, and download the necessary apps if needed (TeX etc.).

Comment: Nothing has to be downloaded. Just follow the links that I provided.

Comment: Sure, I understand this site doesn't use TeX. I won't use the TeX editor here , only on other sites. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

It seems quite logical to assume that the current is flowing parallel to the banks, which are two parallel straight lines, and the text indicates the crossing has to be perpendicular to those lines.

You are supposed to assume that the two movements and so the two velocity vectors, the one coming from the boat's engines and the one from the current, simply superimpose : $\vec{v} = \vec{v}_e + \vec{v}_c$.

That is, in 1 s, your boat movements will be 6 m along its steering direction plus 2 m along the flow direction. The first part of the question is to determine the steering direction so that these two motions combine into a line perpendicular to the flow direction (which corresponds to crossing the river to go to the point directly across). So because $\vec{v}$ needs to be perpendicular to the flow, $\vec{v} \cdot {\vec{v}}_c = 0$. Replacing $\vec{v}$ by the sum above, and knowing the magnitude of $\vec{v}_e$, you can find its angle with the flow.

Then you'll get also how far you get in 1 s, and you'll be able to calculate how much time is needed to cross. Since $\vec{v}$ is aligned in the correct direction, you can do this by calculating its magnitude, which is the speed, and then simply dividing distance by speed. Alternatively, you could use cross product for this, by first calculating the unit vector along the flow, $\vec{c}=\vec{v}_c/|\vec{v}_c|$, and then taking $\vec{v}\times\vec{c}$ (again by replacing $\vec{v}$) : the magnitude of this gives you the speed.

Comment: The lesson is on vectors. Applications of the dot product and cross product specifically is the section in the textbook. Sorry, should've specified.

Comment: OK, well, it doesn't change much the answer.